# Which cloudwatch events are triggered with enhanced health monitoring?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

So I have a worker EB instance with single docker container which reports `EnvironmentHealth` to the cloudwatch. To monitor the health I've setup rule with event pattern:

```
{ "source": [ "aws.health" ] }
```

And there is lambda listening for this event. But nothing seems to be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you refer to EC2 health or container health.

The below AWS guide has the list of all supported cloudwatch events and their json format.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html

Hope this helps !!

Comment: I'm referring to container health. Auto scaling group takes care of ec2 health. But I've setup '/health' url check for container. Even if that shows instance as unhealthy in cloud watch, it doesn't trigger the event.